# DocumentFactory cannot be cast to org.dom4j.DocumentFactory Nested exception

Tags: java, android, intellij-idea, dom4j

I am using `dom4j` in my java library module in **android studio**, on reading the xml file it throws this nested exception. I am unable to figure it out. I have run the same code in `Intellij` for java and it works fine. Any possible reason for this exception?

```
Error:(9, 8) error: 
org.dom4j.DocumentFactory cannot be cast to org.dom4j.DocumentFactory Nested exception: 
org.dom4j.DocumentFactory cannot be cast to org.dom4j.DocumentFactory
Possible causes for this unexpected error include:<ul><li>Gradle's dependency cache may be corrupt (this sometimes occurs after a network connection timeout.)
<a href="syncProject">Re-download dependencies and sync project (requires network)</a></li><li>The state of a Gradle build process (daemon) may be corrupt. Stopping all Gradle daemons may solve this problem.
<a href="stopGradleDaemons">Stop Gradle build processes (requires restart)</a></li><li>Your project may be using a third-party plugin which is not compatible with the other plugins in the project or the version of Gradle requested by the project.</li></ul>In 
the case of corrupt Gradle processes, you can also 
try closing the IDE and then killing all Java processes.
```